# Filepermission in WordPress not working well

Tags: wordpress, ssh, centos, file-permissions, centos6

I've a problem with my WordPress. When I'll upload a media file and W3 Total Cache gives a error with the filepermissions.

When I login with SSH and change the group from example user:user to apache:apache

```
sudo chown -R apache:apache wp-content
```

Everything is fine. W3 Total Cache gives no error and the media upload will work fine. But when I'll change with FTP a file, there is a error that I have no permission to edit the file. When I'll change it back to user:user the errors return in WordPress W3 Total Cache and I can't upload with media

This is with all users on my server. Is there a way to change this, so I have permissions in WordPress en with a external FTP program like Filezilla?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could change it to user:apache permission. Set user group and apache user. It allow Apache to work with this files and allow your FTP client work with same files too.

Comment: Thanks, this is a nice solution!

Answer (score 0):

You could use chrooted ftp using sftp. It's pretty logical to have such issues since the user and group for your ftp user are different than the user/group for the user under which the web server runs